# Task List - Hide "There are no items" with CSR?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, task-list, client-side-rendering

I'm new to SharePoint and I have been asked to remove the string "There are no items..." below a task view (which is a Web Part).

[image: Text to hide for user]

I'm aware that it can be done by using JavaScript (with jQuery for example). 
But can it be done with CSR ?

I'm still looking for a good solution, I keep you advised if I find something that sounds good to me.

Answer (score 5):

As promised, I found the solution.
It can be done using CSR with this line of code when rendering :

```
ctx.ListSchema.NoListItem = "";
```